# Unable to build iOS module on fresh install

Tags: appcelerator

I have installed Appcelerator Studio on macOS and have created a new iOS module without any changes.

When I try to build from the command line or from the studio I get the following issue:

```
clang: clang: error: no such file or directory: 'Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/9.1.0.GA/node_modules/node-ios-device/build'error: 
no such file or directory: 'Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/9.1.0.GA/node_modules/node-ios-device/build'
make: *** [Release/obj.target/node_ios_device/src/device.o] Error 1
make: *** [Release/obj.target/node_ios_device/src/device.o] Error 1
gypgyp  ERR!ERR!  build errorbuild error 
 
gypgyp  ERR!ERR!  stackstack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
 Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
```

The full log is also pasted below:

```
Darrans-MBP:ios darrankelinske$ appc run -p ios --build-only
Appcelerator Command-Line Interface, version 8.1.0
Copyright (c) 2014-2020, Appcelerator, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.

(node:8084) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'padLevels' of module exports inside circular dependency
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
2020-09-04T13:23:45.582Z | ERROR  | An uncaught exception was thrown!
Rebuild failed:
node-pre-gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
node-pre-gyp info using node-pre-gyp@0.10.3
node-pre-gyp info using node@14.9.0 | darwin | x64
node-pre-gyp WARN Using request for node-pre-gyp https download 
node-pre-gyp info check checked for "/Users/darrankelinske/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/9.1.0.GA/node_modules/node-ios-device/binding/node-v83-darwin-x64/node_ios_device.node" (not found)
node-pre-gyp http GET https://appc-node-binaries.s3.amazonaws.com/node-ios-device/v1.7.1/node_ios_device-v1.7.1-node-v83-darwin-x64.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp http 403 https://appc-node-binaries.s3.amazonaws.com/node-ios-device/v1.7.1/node_ios_device-v1.7.1-node-v83-darwin-x64.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp WARN Tried to download(403): https://appc-node-binaries.s3.amazonaws.com/node-ios-device/v1.7.1/node_ios_device-v1.7.1-node-v83-darwin-x64.tar.gz 
node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not found for node-ios-device@1.7.1 and node@14.9.0 (node-v83 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
node-pre-gyp http 403 status code downloading tarball https://appc-node-binaries.s3.amazonaws.com/node-ios-device/v1.7.1/node_ios_device-v1.7.1-node-v83-darwin-x64.tar.gz 
node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not installable for node-ios-device@1.7.1 and node@14.9.0 (node-v83 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
node-pre-gyp WARN Hit error Connection closed while downloading tarball file 
gypgyp  info infoit worked if it ends with  ok
it worked if it ends with ok
gypgyp  infoinfo  usingusing node-gyp@5.1.0
 node-gyp@5.1.0
gypgyp  infoinfo  usingusing node@14.9.0 | darwin | x64
 node@14.9.0 | darwin | x64
gypgyp  infoinfo  okok 
 
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@5.1.0
gyp info using node@14.9.0 | darwin | x64
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@5.1.0
gyp info using node@14.9.0 | darwin | x64
gyp info find Python using Python version 2.7.16 found at "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python"
gyp info find Python using Python version 2.7.16 found at "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python"
gyp info spawn /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
gyp info gyp spawn args [
gyp info spawn args   '/Users/darrankelinske/.appcelerator/install/8.1.0/package/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
info spawn /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-f',
gyp info spawn args   'make',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/Users/darrankelinske/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/9.1.0.GA/node_modules/node-ios-device/build/config.gypi',
gyp info spawn argsgyp info spawn args [
gyp info spawn args   '/Users/darrankelinske/.appcelerator/install/8.1.0/package/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-f',
gyp info spawn args   'make',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/Users/darrankelinske/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/9.1.0.GA/node_modules/node-ios-device/build/config.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/Users/darrankelinske/.appcelerator/install/8.1.0/package/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/Users/darrankelinske/Library/Caches/node-gyp/14.9.0/include/node/common.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/Users/darrankelinske/Library/Caches/node-gyp/14.9.0',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/Users/darrankelinske/.appcelerator/install/8.1.0/package/node_modules/node-gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/Users/darrankelinske/Library/Caches/node-gyp/14.9.0/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/Users/darrankelinske/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/9.1.0.GA/node_modules/node-ios-device',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
gyp info spawn args   'build',
gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
gyp info spawn args ]
   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/Users/darrankelinske/.appcelerator/install/8.1.0/package/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/Users/darrankelinske/Library/Caches/node-gyp/14.9.0/include/node/common.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/Users/darrankelinske/Library/Caches/node-gyp/14.9.0',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/Users/darrankelinske/.appcelerator/install/8.1.0/package/node_modules/node-gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/Users/darrankelinske/Library/Caches/node-gyp/14.9.0/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/Users/darrankelinske/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/9.1.0.GA/node_modules/node-ios-device',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
gyp info spawn args   'build',
gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
gyp info spawn args ]
gyp gypinfo ok 
 info ok 
gypgyp info it worked if it ends with ok
 info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@5.1.0
gyp info gyp usinginfo using node-gyp@5.1.0
 node@14.9.0 | darwin | x64
gyp info using node@14.9.0 | darwin | x64
gypgyp info  infospawn  make
spawn make
gypgyp  infoinfo  spawn argsspawn args [ 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' ]
 [ 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' ]
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/9.1.0.GA/node_modules/node-ios-device/build'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/9.1.0.GA/node_modules/node-ios-device/build'
make: *** [Release/obj.target/node_ios_device/src/device.o] Error 1
make: *** [Release/obj.target/node_ios_device/src/device.o] Error 1
gypgyp ERR! build error  
ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gypgyp  ERR!ERR!  stackstack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
     at ChildProcess.onExit (/Users/darrankelinske/.appcelerator/install/8.1.0/package/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:194:23)
gypgyp  ERR!ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:314:20)
gyp  ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:276:12)
stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/Users/darrankelinske/.appcelerator/install/8.1.0/package/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:194:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:314:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:276:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 19.6.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/Users/darrankelinske/.appcelerator/install/8.1.0/package/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "build" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=/Users/darrankelinske/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/9.1.0.GA/node_modules/node-ios-device/binding/node-v83-darwin-x64/node_ios_device.node" "--module_name=node_ios_device" "--module_path=/Users/darrankelinske/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/9.1.0.GA/node_modules/node-ios-device/binding/node-v83-darwin-x64" "--napi_version=6" "--node_abi_napi=napi"
gypgyp  ERR!ERR!  Systemcwd Darwin 19.6.0
 /Users/darrankelinske/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/9.1.0.GA/node_modules/node-ios-device
gyp ERR! gypcommand "/usr/local/bin/node" "/Users/darrankelinske/.appcelerator/install/8.1.0/package/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "build" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=/Users/darrankelinske/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/9.1.0.GA/node_modules/node-ios-device/binding/node-v83-darwin-x64/node_ios_device.node" "--module_name=node_ios_device" "--module_path=/Users/darrankelinske/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/9.1.0.GA/node_modules/node-ios-device/binding/node-v83-darwin-x64" "--napi_version=6" "--node_abi_napi=napi"
gyp  ERR! cwdERR! /Users/darrankelinske/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/9.1.0.GA/node_modules/node-ios-device
 gypnode -v  v14.9.0
ERR! node -v v14.9.0
gyp gypERR!  ERR!node-gyp -v  v5.1.0
node-gyp -v v5.1.0
gyp gypERR!  ERR!not ok  
not ok 
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /Users/darrankelinske/.appcelerator/install/8.1.0/package/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --module=/Users/darrankelinske/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/9.1.0.GA/node_modules/node-ios-device/binding/node-v83-darwin-x64/node_ios_device.node --module_name=node_ios_device --module_path=/Users/darrankelinske/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/9.1.0.GA/node_modules/node-ios-device/binding/node-v83-darwin-x64 --napi_version=6 --node_abi_napi=napi' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/darrankelinske/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/9.1.0.GA/node_modules/node-ios-device/node_modules/node-pre-gyp-init/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:314:20)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1047:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:287:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Darwin 19.6.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/Users/darrankelinske/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/9.1.0.GA/node_modules/node-ios-device/node_modules/node-pre-gyp-init/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /Users/darrankelinske/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/9.1.0.GA/node_modules/node-ios-device
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v14.9.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.10.3
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
2020-09-04T13:23:45.583Z | ERROR  | Rebuild failed:
node-pre-gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
node-pre-gyp info using node-pre-gyp@0.10.3
node-pre-gyp info using node@14.9.0 | darwin | x64
node-pre-gyp WARN Using request for node-pre-gyp https download 
node-pre-gyp info check checked for "/Users/darrankelinske/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/9.1.0.GA/node_modules/node-ios-device/binding/node-v83-darwin-x64/node_ios_device.node" (not found)
node-pre-gyp http GET https://appc-node-binaries.s3.amazonaws.com/node-ios-device/v1.7.1/node_ios_device-v1.7.1-node-v83-darwin-x64.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp http 403 https://appc-node-binaries.s3.amazonaws.com/node-ios-device/v1.7.1/node_ios_device-v1.7.1-node-v83-darwin-x64.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp WARN Tried to download(403): https://appc-node-binaries.s3.amazonaws.com/node-ios-device/v1.7.1/node_ios_device-v1.7.1-node-v83-darwin-x64.tar.gz 
node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not found for node-ios-device@1.7.1 and node@14.9.0 (node-v83 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
node-pre-gyp http 403 status code downloading tarball https://appc-node-binaries.s3.amazonaws.com/node-ios-device/v1.7.1/node_ios_device-v1.7.1-node-v83-darwin-x64.tar.gz 
node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not installable for node-ios-device@1.7.1 and node@14.9.0 (node-v83 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
node-pre-gyp WARN Hit error Connection closed while downloading tarball file 
gypgyp  info infoit worked if it ends with  ok
it worked if it ends with ok
gypgyp  infoinfo  usingusing node-gyp@5.1.0
 node-gyp@5.1.0
gypgyp  infoinfo  usingusing node@14.9.0 | darwin | x64
 node@14.9.0 | darwin | x64
gypgyp  infoinfo  okok 
 
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@5.1.0
gyp info using node@14.9.0 | darwin | x64
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@5.1.0
gyp info using node@14.9.0 | darwin | x64
gyp info find Python using Python version 2.7.16 found at "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python"
gyp info find Python using Python version 2.7.16 found at "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python"
gyp info spawn /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
gyp info gyp spawn args [
gyp info spawn args   '/Users/darrankelinske/.appcelerator/install/8.1.0/package/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
info spawn /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-f',
gyp info spawn args   'make',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/Users/darrankelinske/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/9.1.0.GA/node_modules/node-ios-device/build/config.gypi',
gyp info spawn argsgyp info spawn args [
gyp info spawn args   '/Users/darrankelinske/.appcelerator/install/8.1.0/package/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-f',
gyp info spawn args   'make',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/Users/darrankelinske/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/9.1.0.GA/node_modules/node-ios-device/build/config.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/Users/darrankelinske/.appcelerator/install/8.1.0/package/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/Users/darrankelinske/Library/Caches/node-gyp/14.9.0/include/node/common.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/Users/darrankelinske/Library/Caches/node-gyp/14.9.0',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/Users/darrankelinske/.appcelerator/install/8.1.0/package/node_modules/node-gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/Users/darrankelinske/Library/Caches/node-gyp/14.9.0/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/Users/darrankelinske/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/9.1.0.GA/node_modules/node-ios-device',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
gyp info spawn args   'build',
gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
gyp info spawn args ]
   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/Users/darrankelinske/.appcelerator/install/8.1.0/package/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/Users/darrankelinske/Library/Caches/node-gyp/14.9.0/include/node/common.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/Users/darrankelinske/Library/Caches/node-gyp/14.9.0',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/Users/darrankelinske/.appcelerator/install/8.1.0/package/node_modules/node-gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/Users/darrankelinske/Library/Caches/node-gyp/14.9.0/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/Users/darrankelinske/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/9.1.0.GA/node_modules/node-ios-device',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
gyp info spawn args   'build',
gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
gyp info spawn args ]
gyp gypinfo ok 
 info ok 
gypgyp info it worked if it ends with ok
 info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@5.1.0
gyp info gyp usinginfo using node-gyp@5.1.0
 node@14.9.0 | darwin | x64
gyp info using node@14.9.0 | darwin | x64
gypgyp info  infospawn  make
spawn make
gypgyp  infoinfo  spawn argsspawn args [ 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' ]
 [ 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' ]
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/9.1.0.GA/node_modules/node-ios-device/build'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/9.1.0.GA/node_modules/node-ios-device/build'
make: *** [Release/obj.target/node_ios_device/src/device.o] Error 1
make: *** [Release/obj.target/node_ios_device/src/device.o] Error 1
gypgyp ERR! build error  
ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gypgyp  ERR!ERR!  stackstack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
     at ChildProcess.onExit (/Users/darrankelinske/.appcelerator/install/8.1.0/package/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:194:23)
gypgyp  ERR!ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:314:20)
gyp  ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:276:12)
stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/Users/darrankelinske/.appcelerator/install/8.1.0/package/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:194:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:314:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:276:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 19.6.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/Users/darrankelinske/.appcelerator/install/8.1.0/package/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "build" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=/Users/darrankelinske/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/9.1.0.GA/node_modules/node-ios-device/binding/node-v83-darwin-x64/node_ios_device.node" "--module_name=node_ios_device" "--module_path=/Users/darrankelinske/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/9.1.0.GA/node_modules/node-ios-device/binding/node-v83-darwin-x64" "--napi_version=6" "--node_abi_napi=napi"
gypgyp  ERR!ERR!  Systemcwd Darwin 19.6.0
 /Users/darrankelinske/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/9.1.0.GA/node_modules/node-ios-device
gyp ERR! gypcommand "/usr/local/bin/node" "/Users/darrankelinske/.appcelerator/install/8.1.0/package/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "build" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=/Users/darrankelinske/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/9.1.0.GA/node_modules/node-ios-device/binding/node-v83-darwin-x64/node_ios_device.node" "--module_name=node_ios_device" "--module_path=/Users/darrankelinske/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/9.1.0.GA/node_modules/node-ios-device/binding/node-v83-darwin-x64" "--napi_version=6" "--node_abi_napi=napi"
gyp  ERR! cwdERR! /Users/darrankelinske/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/9.1.0.GA/node_modules/node-ios-device
 gypnode -v  v14.9.0
ERR! node -v v14.9.0
gyp gypERR!  ERR!node-gyp -v  v5.1.0
node-gyp -v v5.1.0
gyp gypERR!  ERR!not ok  
not ok 
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /Users/darrankelinske/.appcelerator/install/8.1.0/package/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --module=/Users/darrankelinske/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/9.1.0.GA/node_modules/node-ios-device/binding/node-v83-darwin-x64/node_ios_device.node --module_name=node_ios_device --module_path=/Users/darrankelinske/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/9.1.0.GA/node_modules/node-ios-device/binding/node-v83-darwin-x64 --napi_version=6 --node_abi_napi=napi' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/darrankelinske/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/9.1.0.GA/node_modules/node-ios-device/node_modules/node-pre-gyp-init/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:314:20)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1047:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:287:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Darwin 19.6.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/Users/darrankelinske/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/9.1.0.GA/node_modules/node-ios-device/node_modules/node-pre-gyp-init/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /Users/darrankelinske/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/9.1.0.GA/node_modules/node-ios-device
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v14.9.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.10.3
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
Darrans-MBP:ios darrankelinske$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else that hits this idiotic issue, you have to install

Node version: `12.18.3` or probably any `12.x` release

You can find it here:

https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v12.x/

14.x will not work!

Source:

https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides2/Installing+Node